# Issue on Outlook 2010 Add-on Application Debugging Actions on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook

Can someone please help me with my issue on debugging an Outlook Add-on application which was developed using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, Outlook 2010 Add-on with .Net Framework version 4.5?

After I build the Outlook Add-on application, i clicked Start > Debug and the Outlook successfully launched. The Add-on application already appeared on the menu bar of the Outlook but when I click the button, the application did not return to VS debug screen so I can check how does the program goes.

Hope someone can enlighten me on this.

Thank you.